# Import a specific attribute of an asset into another for transaction in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i am working on hyperledger composer, and i am having trouble in understanding relatioship and how it works exactly. 
I have two models named as CHEQUEBOOK and CHEQUE.

I have transaction of creating a CHEQUE and it has it properties. But i want to import CHEQUEBOOKNUMBER from the asset CHEQUEBOOK that has been already created.

How can i achieve such functionality. Is it possible to check if an asset exists or not with the CHEQUEBOOKNUMBER or not

**EDIT**
Sorry about that. This is what i was able to put together by following official tutorials. There might be ton of mistakes as i am still learning.

**First Model file**

```
namespace org.example.bank.chequeBooks
asset chequeBook identified by chequeBookNumber{
o Integer chequeBookNumber 

}
```

**Second Model file**

```
namespace org.example.bank.cheque

import org.example.bank.chequeBooks.chequeBook

asset cheque identified by chequeNumber{
o Integer chequeNumber
--> chequeBook cb
}

transaction chequeInProcess{
o Integer chequeNumber
o Integer chequeBookNumber
}

event chequeCashed{
o Integer chequeNumber
o Integer chequeBookNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would help if you posted your model...

So given this model

```
asset Chequebook identified by cid {

o String cid
o Integer chequenumber

}

transaction Cheque {
--> Chequebook cb
o Integer number
}
```

you would update it as follows in your transaction (incl checking it exists):

```
async function updatechqno(cheque) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

// set the new owner of the commodity
cheque.cb.chequenumber = cheque.number ;

const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.trading.Chequebook');


// check if it exists in the registry
const validno = await assetRegistry.exists(cheque.cb.cid);

console.log("Invoked Chequebook ID submitted is " + cheque.cb.cid ) ; // ie from the transaction

// does it exist (true / false)

if (validno) {
 console.log('it exists, carry on');
} else {
  console.log('doesnt exist, cant carry on');
  throw new Error('this transaction failed, no such ID');
}

// persist the state of the commodity
await assetRegistry.update(cheque.cb);
```

}

Comment: ok, you added the model after I posted the above. But you should, by now, be able to apply the principle of what I've shown to your situation.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me understand.

Comment: Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.example.trading.Chequebook' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist                                               Above error is produced when i try to execute transaction

Comment: you need system ACLs probably - check out sample networks https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/tree/master/packages/trade-network for examples on `permissions.acl`

Comment: I think i have I figured it out.

Comment: Actually it was not pointing to asset that was created. It was pointing to model file itself. I changed it to const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.trading.Chequebook.Chequebook'); And now it works perfectly. Thanks again